# Ignoring case on E4X node names and attributes?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, actionscript, case, e4x

Does anyone know of a trick to ignore upper/lower/camelcase on XML node names and attributes?

A quick example: I give an XML file to my client which contains an XML attribute named fooID but the client could change the XML, and - not being aware of upper/lowercaseness change or add an attribute under 'fooid'. Naturally my parser (in AS3) would ignore the all lowercase attribute. Note that the value contained in fooID isn't the problem here but the attribute name itself. Any ideas?

Comment: I doubt it. XML is by nature case sensitive, so `fooid` is as different from `fooID` as it is from `potato193638_lemons`. You would need a postprocessing step to rename every node to the preferred case.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/868850/how-to-get-case-insensitive-elements-in-xml

Comment: thnx bobince I thought as much. it would probably be possible to process the raw xml string and check for every xml tag (e.g. via regexp) and convert it's case. but that would be a hell of overhead work just to make sure that any typos are ignored. it would actually be cool if the AS3 XML and XMLList classes had a property like 'ignoreCase'!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get case-insensitive elements in XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/868850/how-to-get-case-insensitive-elements-in-xml)

Answer (score 1):

use RegExp in your xml query, and have it case insensitive

const list:XMLList = xml.*.(@name.toString().search( new RegExp("hello", "i") )!= -1);

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own XML parser (the old, pre-E4X way), in which you loop through all nodes recursively, look for the node names of your choice, and then write out an object graph or store the parsed XML in other ways. This involves testing each node name against any allowed node name (pseudo code: `if nodename == "fooID" then do something with the node`). Because you're iffing on each node, you can normalize the matching by lowercasing both nodename and "fooID".

Cumbersome, but does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```
var lowerCasePropertyName:String = propertyName.toLowerCase();
var xmlItem:XMLList = xml.*.(attribute("name").toString().toLowerCase()==lowerCasePropertyName);
```